# Remainder Theorem problem: In whole number division how does r(x) = r?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, r(x) = r when d(x) has degree = 1.

But for whole number problems I am having a problem seeing the connection:

Say, 20/7

The remainder is 6/7ths - therefore we need to include the divisor in the remainder. The remainder is of the form r(x) right?

Also, if we convert the same problem to a trinomial divided by a binomial.

Convert 7 to binomial (6+1) and 20 to (6)^2 -2(6) -4. Same problem. We should get the same answer.

The Quotient is 6-3 and the remainder becomes -1

6-3 = 3
-1 needs to be taken in context of the divisor to become -1/7 which when combined to quotient of 3 gives the 2 6/7 answer.

But is the remainder thereom saying that the remainder of -1 is a constant?

Any help appreciated. It's probably something fundamental that i'm not seeing.

Comment: You should say that the *quotient* of $20/7$ is $2$ and $6/7$.  The remainder is $6$ since $20 = 2 \cdot 7 + 6$.

Comment: Right but from D(x)/d(x) = Q(x) + r(x)  - that would make 20/7 = 2 + 6? Or do you just mean that Q(x) includes the 6/7?

Comment: If you write $20 = 6^2 - 3 \cdot 6 + 2$, then you will get a remainder of $6$.  Taking $x = 6$, dividing $x^2 - 3x + 2$ by $x + 1$ gives a quotient of $x - 4$ and a remainder of $6$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @AndrewDooley If you use polynomial division or the usual division by hand, at some point you cannot continue the division. What remains at this point is the remainder. In the case of polynomials , it is a polynomial with degree less than the degree of the divisor. In the case of division of positive integers, it is a non-negative integer smaller than the divisor.

Comment: If we write $20/7=2+6/7$ , $2$ is the integer part and $6/7$ the fractional part of the number 20/7.

Comment: Thank you. But isn't the remainder always expressed as a numerator with the divisor as the denominator? So for @N.F.Taussig example above: ^2−3+2  by +1 gives a quotient of −4 and a remainder of 6. Wouldn't that 6 need to be over +1? I see that intuitively the remainder should be just 2.

Comment: It depends on how you wish to express your answer.  If you wish to write the answer in the form $D(x) = q(x)d(x) + r(x)$, where $D(x)$ is the dividend, $q(x)$ is the quotient, $d(x)$ is the divisor, and $r(x)$ is the remainder, then $x^2 - 3x + 2 = (x - 4)(x + 1) + 6$, as you can verify.  On the other hand, if you wish to include the remainder term as part of the quotient, then you would write $x^2 - 3x + 2 = (x + 1)\left(x - 4 + \frac{6}{x + 1}\right)$.  I chose to express $20$ as $6^2 - 3 \cdot 6 + 2$, so that the remainder would be positive when dividing by $6 + 1$.  I then took $x = 6$.

Comment: I see now. Thank you.